# Changes not showing up in a file in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

The problem that I'm facing is that any changes I make in feed.js and sidebar.jsx are not being reflected in the react website. However, changes in navbar.jsx are being immediately reflected in the website. Even completely stopping and starting the react app doesn't reflect the changes in the website.

When troubleshooting, I first thought the error was originating from the React Router but after checking everything in it for hours, I think that the problem isn't coming from there.

If I had to guess I think the problem is somewhere in the import/export of files but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Feed from "./components/Feed";
import VideoChannel from "./components/VideoChannel";
import VideoDetail from "./components/VideoDetail";
import SearchFeed from "./components/SearchFeed";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: "#5c44ad" }}>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/ImportElement/:id" exact element = {<ImportElement />} />
        <Route path="/Sidebar/:id" exact element={<Sidebar />} />
        <Route path="/Feed/:" exact element={<Feed />} />
        <Route path="/video/:id" exact element={<VideoDetail />} />
        <Route path="/channel/:id" exact element={<VideoChannel />} />
        <Route path="/search/:searchTerm" exact element={<SearchFeed />} />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Sidebar.jsx

```
import {Stack} from '@mui/material'
import {categories} from '../utils/constant'
const selectedCategory='New';
const Sidebar = () => (
  <Stack direction="row" sx={{overflowY:"auto",
height:{sx:'auto',md:'95%'},
flexDirection:{md:'column'},
}}>
    {categories.map((category)=>(
        <button className='category-btn'
        style={{
            background:category.name===selectedCategory&& '#5c44ad',
            color:'green'
        }}
        key={category.name}>
            <span>{category.icon}</span>
            <span>{category.name}</span>
        </button>
    ))}
</Stack>
)

export default Sidebar
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import { Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { logo } from "../utils/constant";
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

const Navbar = () => (
  <Stack
    direction="row"
    alignItems="center"
    p={2}
    sx={{
      position: "sticky",
      background: "#000",
      top: 0,
      justifyContent: "space-around",
    }}
  >
    <Link to="/" style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center'}}>
      <img src={logo} alt="logo" height={45}/>
    </Link>
    <SearchBar/>
  </Stack>
);

export default Navbar;
```

Feed.js

```
//import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

const Feed = () => {
  return (
    //px is for padding
    //using sx and md to make the property dynamic for smaller and mrdium devices respectively
    <Stack sx={{ flexDirection: { sx: "column", md: "row" } }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          height: { sx: "auto", md: "9200vh" },
          borderRight: "100px solid #3d3d3d",
          px: { sx: 0, md: 2 },
        }}
      >
       < Sidebar/>
     <Typography className="copyright" variant="body2" sx={{mt:1.5,color:'#fff'}}>
       Copyright 2020 JSM Media 
     </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Stack>

    )
}
export default Feed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the **return** statement within sidebar.jsx which will return the React elements to be rendered in the render method. Due to this your jsx file doesn't show the appropriate view.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div> </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Okay, I just added the return (with proper syntax) within sidebar.js but it still doesn't render the elements in the browser. I also noticed that in navbar.jsx I hadn't added a return statement but it still was rendering the elements properly, while in Feed.js I already had a return statement in but it still wasn't rendering the elements in the browser.

Comment: Can you share your file structure? Maybe it's something related to how you are importing each file.

Comment: How do I share a file structure? A screenshot of the folder or would you suggest some other way?